# Can I use Kinect for XBOX for starting Programming using Kinect in Windows PC

Tags: kinect

1) What else do I need to start coding?
2) Also please point me to some getting started resources.

Comment: your question shows you did not do the least bit of "research"; please try googling it first. You will find everything you need in a couple of seconds.

Comment: Yes, you'll only be missing near mode.

Comment: @Pandrei Its correct that I didnt spend much time in research, but whatever little research I did I was confused with the results. I knew about the Near mode, I wanted to make sure that that was the only thing and also I saw many resources but I thought if someone knew about a resource that was easier and clear and want to recommend it then I could start with that.